# MediaRecorder prepare fails with setVideoSize 1080p

Tags: android, mediarecorder

I have a `MediaRecorder` object in my project which gets initialized as follows:

```
private void initRecorder() {
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(512 * 1000);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(60);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT);
    String filepath_external = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()  + "/test/";
    File f = new File(filepath_external);
    if(!f.exists()){
        f.mkdirs();
    }
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(filepath_external + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4");
}
```

If I set

```
private static int DISPLAY_WIDTH = 1024;
private static int DISPLAY_HEIGHT = 768;
```

and call `initRecorder()` followed by `mMediaRecorder.prepare()`, everything runs fine.

However, I want to record with the the size of the smartphone's screen. So I use the following code to set the width and height:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
DISPLAY_WIDTH = size.x;
DISPLAY_HEIGHT = size.y;
```

Now the width = 1920 and the height = 1080 (1080p basically). The result is my activity not even starting, yielding the follow error:

> E/MediaRecorder: prepare failed: -2147483648
>
> W/System.err: java.io.IOException: prepare failed.
>
> W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaRecorder._prepare(Native Method)
>
> W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaRecorder.prepare(MediaRecorder.java:873)
>
> W/System.err:     at com.lfdversluis.testrecord.RecordActivity.prepareRecorder(RecordActivity.java:161)

Why is it not working, and how can I make it work?

---

If I print all supported video sizes in `getSupportedVideoSizes()`, I get:

`Optional size: 1920 1080
Optional size: 1440 1080
Optional size: 1280 720
Optional size: 800 450
Optional size: 720 480
Optional size: 640 480
Optional size: 320 240
Optional size: 176 144`

So 1920 by 1080 should be supported...

---

Using the `CamcorderProfile` as follows, i also get 1920 by 1080 as a result. Again,the prepare function fails:

```
CamcorderProfile camcorderProfile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
int cameraWidth = camcorderProfile != null ? camcorderProfile.videoFrameWidth : -1;
int cameraHeight = camcorderProfile != null ? camcorderProfile.videoFrameHeight : -1;
DISPLAY_WIDTH = cameraWidth;
DISPLAY_HEIGHT = cameraHeight;
Log.e("Campcorder profile", String.format("%s %s", DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT));
```

Comment: Why are you hard-coding values, rather than asking the device what video resolutions it supports? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedVideoSizes%28%29

Comment: @CommonsWare, because these are camera parameters and I am currently capturing the screen of the phone. I am aware of the supported sizes method, but I assume there is a difference in capturing the camera and capturing the screen of a device. Having read the docs I see now that it shows the supported video sizes, but it's weird that capturing screen content need to adhere to camera record sizes. Thank you for showing this.

Comment: "I am currently capturing the screen of the phone" -- you mean using the media projection APIs? That wasn't in your question, though now I see the `SURFACE` bit. Jake Wharton uses `CamcorderProfile` in [his Telecine code](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Telecine/blob/master/telecine/src/main/java/com/jakewharton/telecine/RecordingSession.java) to calculate the high-quality recording option's screen size, then uses that to determine how to set up the actual screen recording.

Comment: @CommonsWare, if I print all the supported sizes, i do get 1920 x 1080, so by your theory, the MediaRecorder should work on this dimension, but it does not.

Comment: When you use Jake Wharton's `CamcorderProfile` approach, what happens? I mean, I assume his approach works, since his app is on the Play Store and all.

Comment: Good point, I'll investigate what this profile reports back as suitable dimension to record with.

Comment: @CommonsWare, the ``CamcorderProfile`` also returns 1920 by 1080, so the camcorder approach fails too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the aid of CommonsWare, I found the issue.

Make sure to check the `getSupportedPreviewFrameRates` in the camera params as well. Hardcoding 60 or 30 fps such as in [Telecine](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Telecine/blob/master/telecine/src/main/java/com/jakewharton/telecine/RecordingSession.java) case may not always work on every device. If you use the `CamcorderProfile`, also set the framerate to `camcorderProfile.videoFrameRate;`.